# NEC, use more extension boxes or an access panel?

Tags: electrical, nec

[image]

What is the maximum number of extension boxes you can hang from a ceiling? This is ridiculous and I probably need one or two more to meet the new drywall ceiling. Are junction boxes permitted behind access panels in drywall?

---

OK, I took all of them out, turns out that part of the ceiling is to be exposed anyway. Still, does code neither expressively permit, nor expressively forbid J-boxes behind panels? I have more fun stuff going on behind me that I'm not even willing to photo.

Comment: Holy crow. I think you're already far past the point of being able to reach into the top box (the "BOX" box) to maintain any splices there. It's just not practical to reroute that wiring down to ceiling level?

Comment: That is a work of art.  You sir, are a true artist.

Comment: Not my work!!!111+1, but I've been in there...no fun. @Tester101

Comment: I think of anybody on the panel at the NEC saw this, they would dedicate an entire article to it.  "***Article 315 Mazura's Ever Expanding Box***".

Comment: EL&U, whats a word for laughing and blushing at the same time? Seriously though, any tips here other than piping that rigid down to a new ceiling box? @Tester101

Comment: From ELU - *chagrinning*. (Unless something overheats in there; then it would be *chargrinning*.)

Comment: Regardless of what you can do in terms of making it accessible, I'd bet my left nostril that has at least 3 code violations to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes J boxes can be behind access panels as long as they meet the code's definition of accessible .I would not add to that mess if you can't re work the conduits and re pull the wire as all ready suggested make sure that your access panel meets fire code. If I was going to deal with that and didn't have the means or budget to re do the grc using an access panel. I'd take that apart down to one extension ring and mount a 4 and 11/16 box maybe on the beam to the right or to the left if there is something reasonable to fasten it to (left would make it easier to rework the emt) run flex or emt to your new box from the extension or if there is a Ko available in the original box. Connect the existing flex and emt to the new box. Then work from that box to the one you need in the ceiling. You may need a larger box than a 4 and 11 that will be dependent on how many wires need to be spliced or run through that box.

Comment: "access panel meets fire code" +1